# Evitar espaços desnecessários em textarea com texto padrão

Tags: html

Situação: tenho um elemento `textarea` que possui um texto padrão, que pode depois ser alterado pelo usuário. O texto possui múltiplas linhas.

Problema: o texto leva em consideração os espaços da indentação do código fonte.

Pseudo-código:

```html
    <html>
        <body>
            <textarea>Olá,
            
            Isto é um teste.</textarea>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Ao renderizar a página, o texto dentro do elemento `textarea` aparece assim:

> Olá,
>
> Isto é um teste.

Existe alguma forma de evitar isso?

Comment: Creio que somente JavaScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Via javascript, você poderia fazer da seguinte maneira:

```js
$(function() {
  var textareas = $('textarea.clean');
  $.each(textareas, function(key, value) {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[ ]+/g, ' ').replace(/^[ ]+/m, ''));
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="clean" rows="5">Olá,

            Isto é um teste.</textarea>

<textarea rows="5">Olá,

            Isto é um teste.</textarea>
```

Comment: Será que as quebras de linhas não deveriam ser mantidas, gerando uma saída como `Olá,\n\nIsto é um teste.`?

Comment: Anderson, pode sim, só adaptar a expressão regular. O \s faz referência a qualquer espaço, ele considera quebra de linha e espaços em branco. Bastaria colocar apenas  " " espaço que funcionaria.

Comment: Porque acredito que seja o objetivo da pergunta: apenas remover a indentação, não as quebras de linha.

Comment: Corrigido! Obrigado Anderson, realmente concordo contigo. Agora, apenas colocar espaço não daria certo pois a linha debaixo ficaria com 1 espaço, aí coloquei um segundo replace para resolver este problema.